# What is a good process to avoid changes in backend breaking things in the frontend?

Tags: debugging, frontend, backend, software-design

We have a project in where the backend guys are constantly making changes to their endpoints and sometimes in the frontend we have weird bugs that after talking with the backend guys we discover is a new change they made.

This bugs are sometimes difficult to track and wastes time. Since we have our code working one day and then when the RESTful api is changed without we knowing we see our code no longer working.

What are some good ways to avoid this? What is a good process for avoiding this. How do you do it at your company?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have APIs with a version number. And new backend features, or changes to the backend, should come with a new API version number; the old API version number should always return the same results unchanged.

Then if the backend is changed, they can inform you that there is a new version that you should use, with a new API version number, and you switch to it any time you like.

An additional approach that I use with client software (where this is even more important because I can't force end users to upgrade their software): I check everything that I get from the server, and everything that isn't the way I expect it to be gets logged on developer's machines. So if the server changes what it sends to me, I will know very quickly (and there would be hell to pay if it affects our end users).

Comment: Thanks for input. can you expand in the "I check everything that I get from the server, and everything that isn't the way I expect it to be gets logged on developer's machines."

Answer (score 0):

I accept @gnasher729 answer.  But If we don't versionize our REST API, then we have to follow a different way to handle this kind of issue.

We follow the below approach for communicating the REST API changes. Hope that this will help others as well.

We keep a REST API Definition Document and also WADL in a central location(Git/Project Central) which contains the sample request and response for each web services. So this document would be updated frequently by our backend team whenever they are adding any new services or making any schema changes. Hence by referring this document periodically, our front-end team gets to know about the recent modifications in the API's.